# What does "managed" API means in Windows Phone 8 API

Tags: winapi, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

When learning Windows phone 8 development, I found that its API can be divided into:
1. Managed (.NET API)
2. Managed & Native (Windows Phone Runtime API)
3. Native (Win32 & COM)

My question is why the .NET API is called "Managed". What does this word means?
Thanks.

Comment: Managed means that the code runs under the CLR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET is called *managed*, because object lifetimes are automatically managed by the runtime environment (CLR, Common Language Runtime).

In contrast, native (and COM) code requires that object lifetimes are managed by the developer, either by explicitly invoking the respective cleanup calls (e.g. `delete`, `Release()`), or by using resource management classes (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`, `_com_ptr_t`).

The term *managed* also refers to additional services provided by the CLR as code continues to run, such as memory management (e.g. providing a compacting heap), security (e.g. verifying that an assembly's code is safe/valid), threading, and the like.

Comment: Just adding the exception handling infrastructure provided by the CLR.

Comment: @Pantelis The CLR does not provide an exception handling infrastructure of its own. It simply uses the operating system's SEH (Structured Exception Handling) facilities.

Answer (score 0):

.NET is based on some kind of bytecode similar to the Java Virtual Machine. This allows garbage collection and checks when casting object types.

As far as I know the word "managed" refers to the fact that .NET provides a data management that handles both garbage collection and object casting checks (and something more).

"Managed code" is a synonym for .NET code (as far as it is not mixed with non-.NET-objects).